# Remove post content in RSS feed?

Tags: rss

I want to remove the post content that is displayed in the RSS feed. How can I do this? I just only want it to show a list of post titles and not the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use filters like:

```
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', '__return_empty_string' );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', '__return_empty_string' );
```

to remove the post excerpts and post contents from the feeds (atom, rss, rss2).

But note that this will not remove the corresponding XML nodes from the feed, only their contents.